# runtime error: load of misaligned address

Tags: c++, c, runtime-error, libgit2

I recently encountered this error. The full error is the following.

```
external/libgit2/src/hash/sha1/sha1dc/sha1.c:438:2: runtime error: load of misaligned address 0x6110000205f5 for type 'const uint32_t', which requires 4 byte alignment
0x6110000205f5: note: pointer points here
 65 6e 74 20 64 35 63  30 62 31 35 64 61 30 36  33 38 65 35 31 61 64 31  38 66 37 64 35 37 31 37  36
```

I am using libgit2 library and the runtime error happens in the library code, so I do not post any code. The thing is the programm continues to run fine. What exactly does this error mean ? and how can I fix it at all ?

Comment: That's **C** code, not **C++** code.

Comment: that bug or incompatibility in source code. Most of such were fixed in updates, so either you have old lib that contains those issues or an incompatible  platform (e.g. reporting  no alignment requirements but actually having ones)

Comment: What version of libgit2 are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x6110000205f5` is not an aligned address. (It is one byte off to 4 byte alignment).
This will happen, if you pass an unaligned pointer to the code.

You could either to this manually or use functions from the [memalign family](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html) or for windows [_aligned_alloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 1):

I hit this error too recently. It's caused by libgit2 optimizations. Misaligned loads are not supported by all processors, that is why they are reported as an error by address-sanitizer but libgit2 is checking that it is supported in the current processor, so it is benign.

There is a thread about it here: https://public-inbox.org/git/20190312210626.GA5157@sigill.intra.peff.net/

A workaround is to add this compile flag `-DSHA1DC_FORCE_ALIGNED_ACCESS` which disables the optimization.

Answer (score 1):

The error might be mitigated with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), once libgit2 will have integrated that version.

The codepath that reads from the index v4 had unaligned memory accesses, which has been corrected.

See [commit 4a6ed30](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a6ed30f96c0313dc55fc052707b33d4d3518912) (28 Sep 2022) by [Victoria Dye (`vdye`)](https://github.com/vdye).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 837fdc9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/837fdc900fe1d00c64e02592e6dd7d4e70745800), 07 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`read-cache`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a6ed30f96c0313dc55fc052707b33d4d3518912): avoid misaligned reads in index v4
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Victoria Dye</sup>

> The process for reading the index into memory from disk is to first read its contents into a single memory-mapped file buffer (type '`char *`'), then sequentially convert each on-disk index entry into a corresponding incore '`cache_entry`'.
> To access the contents of the on-disk entry for processing, a moving pointer within the memory-mapped file is cast to type '`struct ondisk_cache_entry *`'.
>
> In index v4, the entries in the on-disk index file are written *without* aligning their first byte to a 4-byte boundary; entries are a variable length (depending on the entry name and whether or not extended flags are used).
> As a result, casting the '`char *`' buffer pointer to '`struct ondisk_cache_entry *`' then accessing its contents in a '`SANITIZE=undefined`' build can trigger the following error:
>
> ```
> read-cache.c:1886:46: runtime error: member access within misaligned
> address <address> for type 'struct ondisk_cache_entry', which requires 4
> byte alignment
> ```
>
> Avoid this error by reading fields directly from the '`char *`' buffer, using the '`offsetof`' individual fields in '`struct ondisk_cache_entry`'.
> Additionally, add documentation describing why the new approach avoids the misaligned address error, as well as advice on how to improve the implementation in the future.

The documentation:

> Parses the contents of the cache entry contained within the '`ondisk`' buffer into a new incore '`cache_entry`'.
>
> Note that '`char *ondisk`' may not be aligned to a 4-byte address interval in index v4, so we cannot cast it to '`struct ondisk_cache_entry *`' and access its members.
>
> Instead, we use the byte offsets of members within the struct to identify where '`get_be16()`', '`get_be32()`', and '`oidread()`' (which can all read from an unaligned memory buffer) should read from the '`ondisk`' buffer into the corresponding incore '`cache_entry`' members.

---

Still with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), the codepath that reads from the index v4 had unaligned memory accesses, which has been corrected.

See [commit 4a6ed30](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a6ed30f96c0313dc55fc052707b33d4d3518912) (28 Sep 2022) by [Victoria Dye (`vdye`)](https://github.com/vdye).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 837fdc9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/837fdc900fe1d00c64e02592e6dd7d4e70745800), 07 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`read-cache`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a6ed30f96c0313dc55fc052707b33d4d3518912): avoid misaligned reads in index v4
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Victoria Dye</sup>

> The process for reading the index into memory from disk is to first read its contents into a single memory-mapped file buffer (type 'char *'), then sequentially convert each on-disk index entry into a corresponding incore '`cache_entry`'.
> To access the contents of the on-disk entry for processing, a moving pointer within the memory-mapped file is cast to type '`struct ondisk_cache_entry *`'.
>
> In index v4, the entries in the on-disk index file are written *without* aligning their first byte to a 4-byte boundary; entries are a variable length (depending on the entry name and whether or not extended flags are used).
> As a result, casting the '`char *`' buffer pointer to '`struct ondisk_cache_entry *`' then accessing its contents in a '`SANITIZE=undefined`' build can trigger the following error:
>
> ```
> read-cache.c:1886:46: runtime error: member access within misaligned
> address <address> for type 'struct ondisk_cache_entry', which requires 4
> byte alignment
> ```
>
> Avoid this error by reading fields directly from the '`char *`' buffer, using the '`offsetof`' individual fields in '`struct ondisk_cache_entry`'.